# How can I develop games on android devices

Tags: java, android, c++

I want to develop games on android, am good with java.

i already tried using bitmaps and canvas to cook up a sample game, just a ball bouncing in the screen, but had issues with placing more items and stuffs.

I was told to go learn c++, can't i use java to build it? and if so how can i get API and documentation to help me in game development?

(need help thanks.)

Comment: Java can very much be used for this. I'm currently writing a full 3D game in Java so don't listen to anyone who says you can't use java for games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to know c++ to be able to program games on android. Go follow this tutorial and learn OpenGL ES 2.0:

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

This will help you in being able to learn shapes and then show you how to animate your shapes. For your purposes, I would say this is a great start.